# Unable to set KendoUI DropDownList selected index

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I'm facing a problem setting the default index of a KendoUI dropdownlist.

Consider the following code:

```
<body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {

    var data = [{ text: "Tutti", value: 1 },
        { text: "Modifiche Anagrafiche", value: 2 },
        { text: "Rinnovi", value: 3 },
        { text: "Consuntivi", value: 4 },
    ];
    var dropdownlist = $('#comboBox').kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "text",
        dataValueField: "value",
        dataSource: data
    });

    dropdownlist.select(2);
});
</script>
</body>
```

I think I'm making a really stupid error, but I can't figure it out

For simplicity, I've created a Dojo [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/UjoKuMok/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the examples and documentation at https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/methods/select, you have to select the "data-kendoDropDownList" attribute from the DOM element to which you attached the dropdownlist, and run the select method on the object returned by the data- attribute.

So in your code above you simply need to change

```
dropdownlist.select(2);
```

to

```
dropdownlist.data("kendoDropDownList").select(2);
```

Bear in mind that of course this selects the item at index "2" in the dropdown. It does not select it by the value of the item. So the expected result of this change now is that the "Rinnovi" item becomes selected.

See https://dojo.telerik.com/UjoKuMok/5 for a working demo.